# Pandas Aggregate by Month with 2 columns as index

Tags: python, pandas

Sample dataframe:

```
Date       | ID | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3
-----------------------------------------
2017-06-05 | 1  | 2      | 1      | 0
2017-08-05 | 1  | 0      | 1      | 0
2017-10-05 | 1  | 2      | 1      | 1
2017-06-05 | 2  | 0      | 1      | 0
2017-07-05 | 2  | 2      | 0      | 0
2017-09-15 | 3  | 0      | 0      | 5
```

I want to groupby on monthly basis such that each ID has row per month until the last available data. For example, in this case, ID=1 has data from 6th to 10th Month. So, ID=1 gets rows monthly from 6th till 10th month.

Expected output for ID=1:

```
Date       | ID | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3
-----------------------------------------
2017-06-05 | 1  | 2      | 1      | 0
2017-07-05 | 1  | 2      | 1      | 0
2017-08-05 | 1  | 0      | 1      | 0
2017-09-05 | 1  | 0      | 1      | 0
2017-10-05 | 1  | 2      | 1      | 1
```

It can be observed that the type columns don't sum up, instead the past data fills up the row. Like, for data on month 7th is using month 6th same data.

**Below Scenario is out of scope for this question:**
In case the input dataframe has multiple rows within same month.

```
Date       | ID | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3
-----------------------------------------
2017-06-05 | 1  | 2      | 1      | 0
2017-06-19 | 1  | 0      | 1      | 0
2017-10-05 | 1  | 2      | 1      | 1
2017-06-05 | 2  | 0      | 1      | 0
2017-06-25 | 2  | 2      | 0      | 0
2017-09-15 | 3  | 0      | 0      | 5
```

How to aggregate in this case such that each month only has a single row per ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is main problem add days, because resample by `MS` - start of month:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
#replace days to 1
t1 = df['Date'].dt.to_period('m').dt.to_timestamp()
a = df['Date'] - t1
#create MultiIndex Series with difference of days from 1's day od month
s = pd.Series(a.values, index=[df['ID'], t1])
print (s)
ID  Date      
1   2017-06-01    4 days
    2017-08-01    4 days
    2017-10-01    4 days
2   2017-06-01    4 days
    2017-07-01    4 days
3   2017-09-01   14 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

#helper df2 for append missing NaNs rows
df2 = df.set_index(['ID','Date'])
#add missing dates with resample by start od month and forward fill NaNs
df1 = df.set_index(['Date']).groupby('ID').resample('MS').ffill()
print (df1)
                ID  Type 1  Type 2  Type 3
ID Date                                   
1  2017-06-01  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
   2017-07-01  1.0     2.0     1.0     0.0
   2017-08-01  1.0     2.0     1.0     0.0
   2017-09-01  1.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
   2017-10-01  1.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
2  2017-06-01  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
   2017-07-01  2.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
3  2017-09-01  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

---

```
#add missing timedeltas by added rows in df1 by forward filling
s1 = s.reindex(df1.index, method='ffill')
print (s1)
ID  Date      
1   2017-06-01    4 days
    2017-07-01    4 days
    2017-08-01    4 days
    2017-09-01    4 days
    2017-10-01    4 days
2   2017-06-01    4 days
    2017-07-01    4 days
3   2017-09-01   14 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

#create final MultiIndex with added timedelta by set_index
mux = [df1.index.get_level_values('ID'),
       df1.index.get_level_values('Date') + s1.values]
#add missing NaNs rows with combine original
df = df1.drop('ID', 1).set_index(mux).combine_first(df2).reset_index()
print (df)
   ID       Date  Type 1  Type 2  Type 3
0   1 2017-06-05     2.0     1.0     0.0
1   1 2017-07-05     2.0     1.0     0.0
2   1 2017-08-05     2.0     1.0     0.0
3   1 2017-09-05     0.0     1.0     0.0
4   1 2017-10-05     0.0     1.0     0.0
5   2 2017-06-05     0.0     1.0     0.0
6   2 2017-07-05     0.0     1.0     0.0
7   3 2017-09-15     0.0     0.0     5.0
```

EDIT:

```
#set days to 1
df['Date'] = df['Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
#aggregate for unique months
df1 = df.groupby(['Date','ID']).sum()
print (df1)
               Type 1  Type 2  Type 3
Date       ID                        
2017-06-01 1        2       2       0
           2        2       1       0
2017-09-01 3        0       0       5
2017-10-01 1        2       1       1

#add missing months by resample
df1 = df1.reset_index(['ID']).groupby('ID').resample('MS').ffill()
print (df1)
               ID  Type 1  Type 2  Type 3
ID Date                                  
1  2017-06-01   1       2       2       0
   2017-07-01   1       2       2       0
   2017-08-01   1       2       2       0
   2017-09-01   1       2       2       0
   2017-10-01   1       2       1       1
2  2017-06-01   2       2       1       0
3  2017-09-01   3       0       0       5
```

Comment: Can you provide little explanation. Comments in the side will be ok too. @jezrael

Comment: Sure, give me a second.

Comment: ```s1 = s.reindex(df1.index, method='ffill')``` throws ```Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!```

Comment: Problem is with sample or real data? Also `resample` working? It should failed too. Also are duplicates in input? Check it by `print (df[df.duplicated(['Date','ID'], keep=False)])`

Comment: ```print (df[df.duplicated(['Date','ID'], keep=False)])``` prints ```Empty DataFrame Columns:[all columns] Index: []``` If I skip s1 and mux lines, and remove .set_index(mux), then it runs smoothly and I get the df succesfully.

Comment: It is realy good. If omit `set_index` then datetimes are correct? No problem if all days are `1` ?

Comment: In my opinion there should be problem with version of pandas, do you use `0.21.0` ?

Comment: Using Pandas v0.20.3

Comment: Maybe it should be problem. Is possible upgrade?

Comment: Since, s1 and mux lines are removed, combine df2 is creating new rows. Hence, removing combine df2. Still debugging. Matches close to the requirement.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have updated the question. I found the s dataframe had duplicate multi index due to multiple data in same month different dates, hence when we normalised to MS, it leads to duplicate row. And during reindex, throws the exception. If you think the new case is different, I will open a new question.

Comment: What is desired output? But not sure if it is possible in pandas :(

Comment: Output should be month wise aggregated. Same like earlier. The time delta can be ignored though. It is ok to not do forward filling and mux step.